# How to remove elements how to delete elemts from one rdd based on other rdd and create new rdd in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have created 2 Rdd's like below

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([(0,'A'),(0,'B'),(1,'D'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,"A"),(2, "B"),(2, "E")])
rdd1=rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x :list(x[1]))
rdd1.collect()
[['A', 'B'], ['D', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'E']]
rdd2=sc.parallelize(['D','E'])
rdd2.collect()
Out[204]: ['D', 'E']
```

Now i want to remove elements from rdd1 if it is presented in rdd2 i.e.

I have 2 elements inside rdd2 `('D','E')`

Now I want to remove this elements from rdd1 .

my expected rdde3 is :

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 1):

First collect all the elements of second rdd into a list. Apply a filter condition then do a groupby.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
rdd=sc.parallelize([(0,'A'),(0,'B'),(1,'D'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,"A"),(2, "B"),(2, "E")])
print(rdd.collect())
rdd1=rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x :list(x[1]))
list1 = rdd1.collect()
print(list1)
rdd2=sc.parallelize(['D','E'])
list2 =rdd2.collect()
print(list2)

rdd2list = rdd2.collect()
filteredrdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] not in rdd2list)
finalrdd=filteredrdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x :list(x[1]))
print(finalrdd.collect())
```

Here is the finalrdd output :

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Update as per your comment :

```
def filter_list(x):
    return [ele for ele in x if ele not in rdd2list]


final2rdd = rdd1.map(lambda x: filter_list(x))
print(final2rdd.collect())
```

Here's the output of final2rdd, same as before :

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: Hi thanks  for reply  but  as per my question i want to filter from rdd1.because i want   do same job(filter) multiple times different level from rdd1. can you  please help me to filter from rdd1 instead of rdd. thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Sai : I have updated the answer as per your comment.

Comment: Hi I have a similar issue but my `rdd1` is a deeply nested data, and i want to remove the fields which are presented in a list, i have raised a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330163/pyspark-use-map-to-iterate-over-a-nested-rdd-and-remove-certain-values