# Pyspark: Remove first N elements from a RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a `RDD` like this:

```py
[('FRO11987', 104),('SNA90258', 550),('ELE91550', 23),('ELE52966', 380),('FRO90334', 63),('FRO84225', 74),('SNA80192', 258)]
```

and I want to remove first N elements from it.

For example if `N = 3`, then the new RDD should be like this:

```py
[('ELE52966', 380),('FRO90334', 63),('FRO84225', 74),('SNA80192', 258)]
```

I had to do some `Maps` and `Reduces`, and as you might know, `Map and reduces` are only available for `RDD`s. But the more important reason, I have a task that should be done only by `RDD`s.

I'm new to `Pyspark` and don't know how to do it. Besides, I've looked for an answer but didn't find anything.

I'd like to just remove the first elements and `not` iterate through all elements.

Thank you for any help you can offer..

Comment: Why are you intrigued to use RDD for this use case? Dataframe would be a much easier option and you can leverage `Window` function to achieve this.

Comment: I had to do some `Maps` and `Reduces`, and as you might know. `Map` and `reduces` are only available for `RDDs`. But the more important reason, I have a task that should be done only by `RDDs`. @DKNY

Comment: Great! Please add this requirement to your question, just to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used pyspark before, but is it possible to get the first n elements first, and then filter with the first n elements?

Here is some code that I try to write to implement, but I am not sure whether it will work. I referred to  [How to remove elements how to delete elemts from one rdd based on other rdd and create new rdd in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614446/how-to-remove-elements-how-to-delete-elemts-from-one-rdd-based-on-other-rdd-and)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
n = 3
rdd = sc.parallelize([('FRO11987', 104),('SNA90258', 550),('ELE91550', 23),('ELE52966', 380),('FRO90334', 63),('FRO84225', 74),('SNA80192', 258)])
rdd_first=rdd.take(n)
first_list = rdd_first.collect()
filtered_rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x not in first_list)
```

Comment: I had the same idea but this is just not efficient if only you want to remove the first elements.

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam If it is the first element, then you can use rdd.first() instead of rdd.take(n). I think the problem that removing the first few elements can be complicated lies in the fact that rdd is not a list, but a dictionary, so it is not really that ordered